# Background Fetch delegate called twice on device when simulate Background Fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-fetch

I added the following method to my app delegate and enabled background fetch in capabilities:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

NSLog(@"Background fetch started...");
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
NSLog(@"Background fetch completed...");
}
```

When I run my app on my device and go to Debug-> Simulate Background Fetch, the background fetch ran twice. It works fine on the simulator. Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong? Is there any workaround?

Comment: This is a bug with iOS 9, but this post helped me find a workaround when I ran into this problem.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105744/performfetchwithcompletionhandler-called-twice-when-simulating-with-xcode